Backend audio chunks aren't playing correctly when I pass them to client
First, I apologize if anything is spelled incorrectly or if I don't explain myself clearly enough as english is not my first languale.
Now to the problem. I am both starting to work with OpenAI API and WebSockets. I understand the basics and started working with it. My problem starts when I try to stream the OpenAI tool text to speech with the streaming response method and then pass the chunks to my web browser. It does work but the audio that I get is awful.
The code to stream the chunks works pretty well when I use it directly in VS Code, which means, I do not use any webservice at all. This is the original code (I got it from OpenAI forum).
import pyaudio
from openai import OpenAI

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=8,
                channels=1,
                rate=24_000,
                output=True)

client = OpenAI()

with client.audio.speech.with_streaming_response.create(
     model="tts-1-hd",
     voice="nova",
     input="some text I want to stream",
     response_format="mp3"
) as response:
     for chunk in response.iter_bytes(1024):
       stream.write(chunk)

As you can see, the audio is streamed directly and not passed through any WebSocket. That works pretty well.
Now, when I tried to use that code with WebSockets I changed the
stream.write(chunk)

for a
socketio.emit('audio_chunk', chunk)

I recieved that chunk into a script.js with the following code.
socket.on('audio_chunk', function (chunk) {
    const arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(chunk).buffer;

    audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, (buffer) => {
        audioBufferQueue.push(buffer);
        playNextInQueue();
    }, (error) => {
        console.error('Error decoding audio data:', error);
    });
});

function playNextInQueue() {
    if (sourceNode || audioBufferQueue.length === 0) return;

    const buffer = audioBufferQueue.shift();
    sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
    sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    sourceNode.onended = () => {
        sourceNode = null;
        playNextInQueue(); 
    };
    sourceNode.start();
}

Like I said at the beginning, it does work, but the audio that comes is awful. Sometimes I don't understand what it says and I don't really know what to do anymore. I know I can produce the full audio with other OpenAI tools, but if the input is too big, the time it gets to finish is quite large.
I want to believe that my javascript is wrong as I'm really new at it. Does anyone know what can I do to get a good audio quality?

According to the documentation for decodeAudioData, that function only works for complete audio files, not partial audio data chunks. Another thing that stands out to me is that you're trying to stream and decode mp3 binary data - you may have more success with a PCM format like wav.

Don't use web sockets.  There's no need for it, and it makes this problem really difficult.  Just use a normal HTTP streaming response, and then you can use a regular audio element.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78718805/362536

@Brad Hey! I couldn't give any answer back until now, but I took your feedback to solve my problem and it worked! Thank you so much!
